# How to store strings in a 2D array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string, char, malloc

I want to store strings in a `char *` array but I don't know how I can do that.
Each cell in the 2d array can contain letters or numbers with 2 digits.

```
|_|S|_|
|_|10|_|
|_|W|_|
|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|
```

I tried this, I used struct:

```
struct Etage {
    char Idsalles[20];
    int** etage;
    int width;
    int height;
}; 


#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "etage.h"

#define COLS 15
#define ROWS 9

Etage *createMap()
{
    Etage *e = malloc(sizeof(Etage));
    e->width = COLS;  // columns
    e->height = ROWS; // rows
    e->etage = malloc(sizeof(char *) * e->height);

    for (int i = 0; i < e->height; i += 1)
    {
        e->etage[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * e->width);
        for (int j = 0; j < e->width; j += 1)
        {
            e->etage[i][j] = "0";
        }
    }

    return e;
}

void randomId(Etage *e, int maxSalles)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i = 0;

    if (maxSalles < 10)
    {
        printf("Seulement %d disponibles, veuiller générer plus de salles.\n", maxSalles);
        return;
    }

    while (i < 10)
    {
        int id = (rand() % maxSalles) + 1; 
        int existe = testId(e, id);
        if (existe != 1)
        {
            e->Idsalles[i] = id;
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    
    return;
}

int testId(Etage *e, int id)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 1)
    {
        if (id == e->Idsalles[i])
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void printEtage(Etage *e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < e->height; i += 1)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < e->width; j += 1)
        {
            if(e->etage[i][j] == 0){
                printf("  ");
            }else{
                printf("%s", e->etage[i][j]);
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Id des salles de cette étage: ");
    for(int i =0; i <10;i+=1){
        printf("%d ",e->Idsalles[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void freeEtage(Etage *e)
{
    //free(e->etage);
    free(e);
}

void placerSalles(Etage* e){
    int a=ROWS/2;
    int b=COLS/2;
    //0 = Haut; 1 = Droite; 2 = Bas; 3 = Gauche
    e->etage[a][b] = e->Idsalles[0]+"\0";    // On place la premiere salle au centre de l'étage sa sera le spawner 'S'
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i = 1;
    while(i<10){
        int dir  = randomDirections();

        if(dir==0){ // On se déplace en haut
            a = a-1;    //On se déplace
            if(e->etage[a][b] == 0 && a > 0){
                e->etage[a][b] = e->Idsalles[i]+"\0";
                i+=1;
            }else{
              a = a+1;  // Sionon on revien a la derniere case connu
            }
        }else if(dir==1){   // On se déplace à droite
            b=b+1;
            if(e->etage[a][b] == 0 && b< e->width){
                e->etage[a][b] = e->Idsalles[i]+"\0";
                i+=1;
            }else{
                b = b-1;
            }
        }else if(dir==2){ // On se déplace en bas
            a = a+1;
            if(e->etage[a][b] == 0 && a>e->height){
                e->etage[a][b] = e->Idsalles[i]+"\0";
                i+=1;
            }else{
                a = a-1;
            }
        }else if(dir==3){ // On se déplace à gauche
            b = b-1;
            if(e->etage[a][b] == 0 && b>0){
                e->etage[a][b] = e->Idsalles[i]+"\0";
                i+=1;
            }else{
                b = b+1;
            }
        }
    }
}

int randomDirections(){
    int i = 0;
    int id = rand() % 4; // Remplacé 10 par le nbrSalles
    //printf("Position: %d\n",id);
    return id;
}
```

I have a good understanding with 2d array but three...

I tried using `malloc`.

I don't even think this is possible...

Comment: `const char* array[x][y] = { {" ", "10", "blah", ...}, { "more", "strings", "here" } };`. If you need them to be writable then 2 for loops and assign using `strdup` or similar.

Comment: As far as I understand the question, there's no special trick involved in doing what you ask.  As such, I'm a bit at a loss as to how to answer.  If you have attempted to write the needed code, then presenting your attempt might help us understand the nature of your uncertainty.  If you have not made such an attempt, then why not?

Comment: @Lundin it is array of pointers not array of strings.

Comment: @JohnBollinger There is what i've done. Thank you for your help

Comment: @0___________ "How to store strings in an array 2d in c"  It's not a 3D array of characters either, apparently.

Comment: Ok.  And what part of that is related to the specific question you're asking?  Or to put it another way, how about restating the question in terms of the code?  And if there are parts of the code that aren't relevant to that (I'm sure there are) then you would help us help you by removing the unneeded parts.

Answer (score 2):

If your string is a maximum of 2 characters long (your strings will be 3 chars long)

```
char array[rows][cols][3] = {{"2", "a", "34"}, ... };
```

or to use malloc

```
char (*array)[cols][3] = malloc(rows * sizeof(*array));
```